# Looking for help in determining the lift of pageviews during a promotion through Power BI and DAX

Tags: powerbi, relational-database, dax

I am trying to analyze the increase in traffic and sales when a certain product is on promotion compared to when it is not. basically for simplicity I want the average pageviews per day when it is on promotion vs average pageviews per day when it is not on promotion.

Each day has a promotion and some days can even have 2 or 3 promotions running at the same time. but each product is not in every promotion and is usually featured 4 or 5 times a year.

I have a table that contains all my pageview data by day and by product. this table is connected to a calendar table by date and a product table by article number.

I then have a promo table that is contains all promotion names, the dates of the promotions and the products included in each promotion. This table is connected to the calendar table by date and product table by article number

I have attached an image that shows what my current visualization looks like, but it doesn't quantify the answer. I can clearly see theres a lift, but what exactly is that lift.

Any ideas of a formula or method i can use to get the average per promotion name or average when promotion name is blank?

[visualizations that show the pageviews by individual day and another for the days only when its on promo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ewFi.png)

[table relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD047.png)

Thanks

Comment: You could calculate average and then check If number of orders is blank then return average else return number of order.

Comment: I'd like to group date by IF there is a promo code or IF promo code is blank to then average amount out over those days. Is that possible?